# How to make a function to find duplicacy in a character string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7

Here is the code I have written to find duplicate characters and then replace them by ')' and original characters by '(' in a string and it should ignore capitalization.

```
def duplicate_finder(word):
    word1 = word.lower();
    w = list(word1);
    w1 = '';
    for i in range(0, len(word1)):
        if ([v in word1.replace(w[i], '') for v in w[i]]==[True]):
            w1 += ')';    
        else:
            w1 += '(';
    return (w1)
```

But this function always returns me '((((((...((' [till the number of characters in the input string]. Can someone please point me the fault in my code!!! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide few examples with expected outputs.

Comment: `word1.replace(w[i],'')` replaces all instances of `w[i]` in `word1`

Comment: What is the input ? How exactly does the `word` input string look like ? And what then if multiple matches are found ? How will the code then behave ? Should he continue to search for other matches even though the brackets have already been overwritten (the original character and the matching first character) ?

Comment: **@Satya**, is `(()()))((()((()()))(` correct output for  input `abaccccsgfsyetgdggdh` & `())())())((((()))))(((()))))()` is for input `AAABBBCCC34519543absd67das1729`?

Comment: NO, if any alphabet is repeated more than once it will replace it by ')' For example 'Success' >> ')())())'

Comment: @KeyurPotdar examples: 'alpha' >> ')((()'
 'Success' >> ')())())'
'Recede' >> '()()()'
Ignoring the capitalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop you run always gives `False` because: `word1.replace(w[i],'')` replaces all instances of `w[i]` in `word1`. So when you look for `v in word1.replace(w[i],'')`, it doesn't find any as you relaced all of them. This calls `w1 += '('` everytime!

---

You can do :

```
>>> def duplicate_finder(word):
...     word1 = word.lower();
...     w = list(word1);
...     w1 = '';
...     for i in range(0, len(word1)):
...         if ([v in word1[:i]+word1[i+1:] for v in w[i]]==[True]):
...             w1 += ')';
...         else:
...             w1 += '(';
...     return (w1)
...
>>> duplicate_finder('hello')
'(())('
```

---

I would do it some other way, involving dictionary keeping counts to get true O(n) algo

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (assuming I understand the question):

```
def duplicate_finder(word):
    word1 = word.lower();
    for c in word1:
        # If more that one occurence of c
        if 1 != word1.count(c):
            # Replace all c with (
            word1 = word1.replace(c, '(')
        # Only one occurence
        else:
            word1 = word1.replace(c, ')')
    return word1
```

Answer (score 1):

`def duplicate_finder(word):
    word = word.lower()
    l = len(word)
    for i in range(l):
        index = word.find(word[i], i+1)
        if index != -1 and word[i] !=')': 
            word = word.replace(word[i], '(', 1)
            word = word.replace(word[index], ')', 1)
    return (word)`

Test:
I gave input as "Sanjana"
[Output screenshot with steps of replacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1JIv.png)

It resulted in s((j))a

**Note:**
`word[i] != ')'` check is necessary as there is a possibility of replacement of already existing `)` in the unseen segment of the string, and thus can produce weird output

**Edit**

`def duplicate_finder(word):
    word = word.lower()
    l = len(word)
    for i in range(l):
        index = word.find(word[i], i+1)
        if word[i] not in [')', '('] : 
            if index != -1:
                word = word.replace(word[i], ')')
            else:
                word = word.replace(word[i], '(')
    return (word)`

Comment: the output should be: '())()))' the target program should count the occurrence of every character and if the occurrence is greater than 1 the replace it by ')' otherwise by '('

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
def duplicate_finder(word):
    word1 = word.lower()
    w1 = ''
    found_chars= set([])
    for c in word1:
        if c in found_chars:
            w1+=')'
        else:
            found_chars.add(c)
            w1+='('
    print w1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def duplicate_finder(word):
    word1 = word.lower();
    w1 = '';
    length = len(word1)
    for i in range(0, length):
        w2 = word1[i]
        if(word1[i] != ")"):
            word1 = word1.replace(word1[i],"(",1)
        for v in range(i+1,length):
            if(word1[v] != ")" and word1[v] != "("):
                if (word1[v] == w2):
                    word1 = word1.replace(w2,")")
    return (word1)
```

Comment: I understand first occurrence of character needs to be replaced with "(" and subsequent duplicates if any with ")"

Answer (score 0):

```
# Find duplicate characters in a string by following conditions:
# - the first (original) character will replaced by '('
# - all others matches will replaced by ')'
# - all in a string with ignore capitalization

def duplicate_finder(word):
    s = word.lower()
    for ch in s:
        if s.count(ch)  >  1:    # is there more copies of this one character ?
            s = s.replace(ch, '(', 1).replace(ch, ')') # the first match will replaced by '(' character, and then all other matches will replaced by ')' character
    return s

print 'result: ' + duplicate_finder('hello world')     # result: he()( w)r)d
#                                    0123456789A                 0123456789A
```

New code (by comment from Satya - at 23:26):

```
# Find duplicate characters in the string by following conditions:
# - all single characters will replaced by '('
# - all multiple characters (duplicates) will replaced by ')'
# - input string must ignore capitalization

def duplicate_finder(word):
    s = word.lower()
    for ch in s:
        if s.count(ch)  >  1:         # is there more copies of this one character ?
            s = s.replace(ch, ')' )   # replace all matched ch by ')'
        else:
            s = s.replace(ch, '(', 1) # replace this one matched ch by '(' - there's only one character
    return s

print 'result: ' + duplicate_finder('hello world')     # result: (()))(()()(
#                                    0123456789A                 0123456789A
```

Comment: I am sorry but from the original, I meant the character in the string which is not repeated even once.

Comment: Again please... do you need solo (single) characters all replaced by "(" ? And all characters what are duplicated by 2x times or more times, do you want them to replace by ")" ? Right ?

Comment: Yes all the repeated characters by ')'

Comment: OK, all done, my second code was appear up there :).

Answer (score 0):

**@Satya**, I have used the concept of **Counter** container of collections module in Python to solve your problem.

> A Counter is a subclass of dict. Therefore it is an unordered collection where elements and their respective count are stored as dictionary. This is equivalent to bag or multiset of other languages.
>
> **Note**: Do not forget to check the References for **Counter** which is give at very bottom of this answer and comment if find any difficulty.

Have a look at the below code.

```
"""
    StkOvrFlw link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485559/how-to-make-a-function-to-find-duplicacy-in-a-character-string
    Aim: [
            '1. Here, original character means the character which '
                'is first time appearing in the string'
            '2. Replacing original character with => ('
            '3. If there are more occurences of original character'
                then replace them with => )'
    ]
    References: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/collection/python-collections-counter
"""
from collections import Counter

# Code
def duplicate_finder(word):
    word = word.lower()
    i = 1;

    for ch, count in Counter(word).items():
        # print '(', i, ') Original character: \'', ch, '\'with', count - 1, 'more occurence(s)'
        if count == 1:
            word = word.replace(ch, '(') # Only 1 occurence of original character   
        else:
            l = list(word)
            l[word.find(ch)] = '('       # Replace original character with (
            word = ''.join(l) 
            word = word.replace(ch, ')') # Replace other occurences of original character with )

        # print 1, 'occurence of \'', ch, '\' replaced with \'(\' and remaining ', count - 1, ' occurence(s) with \')\''
        # print 'Iteration ', i, ' gives: ', word, '\n'
        i += 1
    return word

# Test case 1
print "I/P:  abaccccsgfsyetgdggdh"
print "O/P: ", duplicate_finder('abaccccsgfsyetgdggdh')
"""
I/P:    abaccccsgfsyetgdggdh
O/P:    (()()))((()((()()))(
"""

# Test case 2
print "\nI/P:  AAABBBCCC34519543absd67das1729"
print "O/P: ", duplicate_finder('AAABBBCCC34519543absd67das1729')
"""
I/P:    AAABBBCCC34519543absd67das1729
O/p:    ())())())((((()))))(((()))))()
"""
```

> **References**: You can find nice articles on **Counter** container of Python at:
>
> http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/collection/python-collections-counter and
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counters-in-python-set-1/